# Related to datastage. Adding user variable to parameter

Tags: parameters, datastage

I have an user variable (say for ex `var_ts`) that stores the timestamp using the user variable stage in the job sequence.

Now I want to use the variable value in other jobs in the same job sequence.

How do I add it as a parameter, because when I am adding it the variable name is coming and not the timestamp within.

Answer (score 0):

When you add it as a parameter the user variable name is used, but at runtime the value will be substituted.

For example in the job activity stage for MyTS it will add:

```
UserVariables_Activity_0.var_ts
```

At runtime you will see:

```
CallRowGenToPeek1 -> (RowGenToPeek1): Job run requested
Mode (row/warn limits) = 0/0
Job Parameters --->
MyTS=00:00:00
DSJobController=CallRowGenToPeek1
```

where the value of UserVariables_Activity_0.var_ts is 00:00:00.

Answer (score 0):

You must use Activity Variable on Value Expression of Job Activity parameter.
On the following images there is a sequence with a User Variable **UV** and an Job Activity that call the job **calledJob**. On the UV, there is a variable **var_ts** valued with manipulation on timestamp.

[image: Example Sequence - variable definition]

The job **calledJob** want a only parameter, **Timestamp**. On the Properties of Job Activity calledJob, for the Timestamp parameter, select Activity Variable by 3 dot on right.

[image: Activity Variable]

Now, select UV.var_ts for pass the User Variable value to job.

[image]

[image]